# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo pdf en Django, si tengo una clase que crea dicho pdf?

Tags: django, pdf

esta es mi clase que crea dicho pdf, pero quiero que en vez que muestre el pdf, pueda realizar directamente la descarga al presionar generar pdf

```
class AdminImprimirAdopcion(SuperUsuarioMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            pk = self.kwargs['pk']
            can = Can.objects.get(id=pk)
            edad = relativedelta(datetime.now(), can.fecha_nacimiento).years
            esterilizacion = {'n_tattoo': 'No realizado'}
            if can.esterilizado:
                esterilizacion = Esterilizacion.objects.get(cam_id=can.id)
            vacunas = Vacunas_Can.objects.filter(can_id=pk)
            usuario_adoptivo = Usuario_Adoptivo.objects.get(id=can.id_usuario_adoptivo_id).usuario_id
            usuario = User.objects.get(id=usuario_adoptivo)
            context = {'can': can, 'edad': edad, 'vacunas': vacunas, 'usuario': usuario,
                       'esterilizacion': esterilizacion}
            template = get_template('Administrador/pdf/formulario_adopcion.html')
            html = template.render(context)
            css_url = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/static-pdf/css/bootstrap.min.css')
            pdf = HTML(string=html, base_url=self.request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(stylesheets=[CSS(css_url)])
            return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        except:
            pass
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('vista_listar_adopciones'))

Este es mi link de mi HTML para generar el archivo pdf

<a target = "_blank" href = "{% url 'vista_imprimir_pdf' can.id %}" class = "btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Imprimir</a>
```

¿QUE TENDRIA QUE HACER PARA QUE SE DESCARGUE DIRECTAMENTE Y NO SE MUESTRE EL PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Debes modificar el response para que puedas obtener el pdf

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        can = Can.objects.get(id=pk)
        edad = relativedelta(datetime.now(), can.fecha_nacimiento).years
        esterilizacion = {'n_tattoo': 'No realizado'}
        if can.esterilizado:
            esterilizacion = Esterilizacion.objects.get(cam_id=can.id)
        vacunas = Vacunas_Can.objects.filter(can_id=pk)
        usuario_adoptivo = Usuario_Adoptivo.objects.get(id=can.id_usuario_adoptivo_id).usuario_id
        usuario = User.objects.get(id=usuario_adoptivo)
        context = {'can': can, 'edad': edad, 'vacunas': vacunas, 'usuario': usuario,
                   'esterilizacion': esterilizacion}
        template = get_template('Administrador/pdf/formulario_adopcion.html')
        html = template.render(context)
        css_url = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/static-pdf/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        pdf = HTML(string=html, base_url=self.request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(stylesheets=[CSS(css_url)])
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="formulario_adopcion.pdf"'
        return response
    except:
        pass
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('vista_listar_adopciones'))
```